# Phonegap. Отображение div элемента на всю высоту

Tags: phonegap, css

Пишу

```
#map{
width:100%;
height: 100%;   
position:relative;
top:0px;
}
```

В браузерах отображается на всю высоту. В телефонах вообще не отображается. высота как будто 0%. С шириной проблем нет. Растягивается на всю ширину.

```
<body>
<p id="map"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: покажите шаблон, телепатия не справляется

Comment: Не понимаю о каком шаблоне идет речь?

Comment: попробуй min-height:100%;

Comment: @Радик Камалов, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменяйте относительное позиционирование на абсолютное, у меня прекрасно из-под фонгапа растягивается на весь экран такая верстка:

```
.main {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
<body>
<div class="main"> ... </div>
</body>
```

Comment: c position:absolute; работает. Спасибо.

Comment: ну, так примите мой ответ как правильный :)